# Storing char in array with strcpy

Tags: c

```
char strr[10];
strcpy(strr, argv[1]);
```

This works fine for storing an entire argument but how do i use the same technique
if i want to store a certain char from the first argument.

```
strcpy(strr, argv[1][1]);
```

This wont work ofcourse since its a char, so im wondering how else i can do it

EDIT:
i just used char strr[10]; as an example of an char array. Please dont pay attention to the size of it.

Comment: You cannot do that. You should use something like `strr[0] = argv[1][1];`. This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `strcpy` copies *strings*. To copy a single character just assign to another character variable.

Comment: `argv[1][1]` is a `char`.

Comment: Or you may want `strncpy(strr, &argv[1][1], 1);` (this seems harder to understand)

Comment: And what happens if `argv[1]` is longer than 9 characters?

Comment: Until it's not...

Comment: check the edit, basically dont pay attention the size of the array, the size of it wasent the point of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store a char in array using `strcpy`. `strcpy` is for strings - not chars.

But you can do it in another way.

It's very simple:

```
char strr[2] = { 0 };   // Make strr a string that can hold 1 char and a 
                        // string termination. Initialize to zero.

strr[0] =  argv[1][1];  // Copy the second char of the string pointed to by 
                        // argv[1] to the first char of strr
```

Now `sttr` is a string that holds just one char (and the mandatory string termination).

Besides this code, you need to ensure that `argv[1]` is valid and that `argv[1][1]` is valid.

Something like:

```
char strr[2] = { 0 };   // Make strr a string that can hold 1 char and a 
                        // string termination. Initialize to zero.

if (argc > 1 && strlen(argv[1]) > 1)
{
    strr[0] =  argv[1][1];  // Copy the second char of the string pointed to by 
                            // argv[1] to the first char of strr
}
```